# Large files are not transmitted to an Elastic Beanstalk hosted app

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently working on a web application where I need to store large files (mp4 videos that sometimes have a size greater than 100mb). But, when I am trying to upload them from a static Angular website hosted in a S3 bucket to an API hosted with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I got a error that I don't understand.
[Click here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I63ip.png)

What I tried:

1. There is no problem when uploading PDF. It works perfectly.
2. There is no problem when uploading very short MP4 (3s, 453Kb). It works clean, but a little bit slower than PDF, but still really short (3 seconds). This is why I think the problem could came from the file size.
3. I read on Internet that there's something called client_max_body_size when using Nginx (as AWS does). I tried to increase this default limit by adding this to my project:

   myrootproject/.ebextensions/nginx.conf

   Into nginx.conf:

   ```
   files:
      "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
           content: |
               client_max_body_size 4G;
   ```

   but nothing has changed... or at least it didn't have the desired effect, it still not working.

Additional informations

1. When I do this manipulation in local, it works fine.
2. When I do this manipulation from the hosted website (S3 bucket) to localhosted API, it works fine.
3. It takes really long to have a response from the server (only when this error occurs). I have the feeling that the request don't even access my NodeJS code, because if an error is emit on it, I would handled it.
4. Here is screenshots of my request, if it could help:

   [Request (first part)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI70u.png)
   [Request (second part)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMXx9.png)

I really need help on this one, hoping you can give it to me!

P.S: I created this post with help of a translator. If some parts are strangely written, my apologies,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option `myrootproject/.ebextensions/nginx.conf` does not take effect, probably because you are using **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2) - I assume that you are using AL2. But this config file works only in AL1.

For AL2, the `nginx` settings [should be provided](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not `.ebextentions`. Therefore, for example, you could create the following config file:

**.platform/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.conf**

with the content of:

```
client_max_body_size 4G
```